# Go/Ldap get primary groups of a user

Tags: go, active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

I'm using go/ldap to query my active directory to get all the groups of a specific user, the function is working but is not returning the Primary Groups, like Domain Users.

**Code example**

```
package main
import (
   "encoding/json"
   "errors"
   "fmt"
   "github.com/go-ldap/ldap/v3"
   "github.com/techoner/gophp"
   "handlers"
   "log"
   "reflect"
   "strconv"
   "strings"
)

func main(){
      conn, err := connect(bindServer,BindPort)
      if err != nil {
         log.Printf("Failed to connect to AD/LDAP with error: %s", err)
         return nil, fmt.Errorf("Failed to connect to AD/LDAP with error: %s", err)
      }
      errBind := conn.Bind(bindUser, bindPWD)
      if errBind != nil {
         if isLdapDebug {
            log.Printf("Failed to bind to AD/LDAP with error: %s", errBind)
         }
         return nil, fmt.Errorf("Failed to bind to AD/LDAP with error: %s", errBind)
      }


      searchRequest := ldap.NewSearchRequest(
         DC=domain,DC=local,
         ldap.ScopeWholeSubtree, ldap.NeverDerefAliases, 0, 0, false,
         fmt.Sprintf("(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=%s))", administrator),
         []string{"dn"},
         nil,
      )

      sr, err := conn.Search(searchRequest)

      if err != nil {
         return nil, err
      }

      if len(sr.Entries) != 1 {
         return nil, errors.New("User does not exist")
      }

      userdn := sr.Entries[0].DN
      log.Printf("USER DN IS =%s", userdn)
      searchRequest = ldap.NewSearchRequest(
         DC=domain,DC=local,
         ldap.ScopeWholeSubtree, ldap.NeverDerefAliases, 0, 0, false,
         fmt.Sprintf("(&(objectClass=group)(member=CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=local))"),
         []string{"cn"}, // can it be something else than "cn"?
         nil,
      )
      sr, err = conn.Search(searchRequest)
      if err != nil {
         return nil, err
      }
      
      groups := []string{}
      for _, entry := range sr.Entries {
         //fmt.Printf("%s", entry)
         groups = append(groups, entry.GetAttributeValue("cn"))
      }

      return groups, nil

}
```

**Output**

```
[Administrators Schema Admins Enterprise Admins Domain Admins Group Policy Creator Owners gteste1 gtest2]
```

The groups are correcly returned but is missing the primary groups.

Any way to return all groups of a specific user including Primary Groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the primary group in go using the lib

```
github.com/go-ldap/ldap/v3
```

I had to use this code sample:

```
userdn := sr.Entries[0].DN
groups := []string{}
searchRequest = ldap.NewSearchRequest(
   data.Record.LdapSuffix,
   ldap.ScopeWholeSubtree, ldap.NeverDerefAliases, 0, SearchTimelimit, false,
   fmt.Sprintf("(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(primaryGroupID=513)(sAMAccountName=%s))", ldap.EscapeFilter(username)),
   []string{"primaryGroupID"}, 
   nil,
)
sr, err = conn.Search(searchRequest)
if err != nil {
   continue
}

if len(sr.Entries) > 0 {
   primaryGroup := sr.Entries[0].GetAttributeValue("primaryGroupID")
   if primaryGroup == "513" {
      if searchGroup == "Domain Users" {
         return true
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The primary group is different. You have to look at the `primaryGroupId` attribute on the user, then search for the group that has that value in its `primaryGroupToken` attribute.

In most cases, the `primaryGroupId` will be `513`, which corresponds to the Domain Users group.

A little more detail in an article I wrote on this: [Active Directory: What makes a member a member?](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/06/07/what-makes-a-member.html#the-primary-group)

Comment: Thanks for guide me on right direction